# How to allow HTTPS connections from both localhost and container towards an ASP.NET Core Web API application?

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, https, ssl-certificate

I am trying to use Docker for an existing application and I have the following issue. When the API is trying to get the Identity Server metadata from the container, it fails with the following:

```
web_api          | System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://host.docker.internal:5500/.well-known/openid-configuration'.
web_api          |  ---> System.IO.IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: 'https://host.docker.internal:5500/.well-known/openid-configuration'.
web_api          |  ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
web_api          |  ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
```

This is indeed confirmed by the host browser (certification error in Chrome).

If I access the same metadata using localhost instead of host.docker.internal, it works as expected.

I have used the instructions from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/docker-compose-https?view=aspnetcore-3.1) in order to create and trust a localhost certificate that it is also used by the identity server:

```
dotnet dev-certs https -ep %USERPROFILE%\.aspnet\https\aspnetapp.pfx -p { password here }
dotnet dev-certs https --trust
```

I assume these instructions create the certificate only for localhost, but I am trying to get a solution that also works for host.docker.internal.

**Question:** How to allow HTTPS connections from both localhost and container towards an ASP.NET Core Web API application?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you are right - `dotnet dev-certs` only generates certs for `localhost`. And as far as I can tell is not configurable. So it seems you will have to generate your own self-signed cert and trust it. Assuming you're on Windows, one way to do it is with [Powershell's New-SelfSignedCertificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pkiclient/new-selfsignedcertificate?view=win10-ps):

```bsh
#create a SAN cert for both host.docker.internal and localhost
$cert = New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName "host.docker.internal", "localhost" -CertStoreLocation cert:\localmachine\my

#export it for docker container to pick up later
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "123123" -Force -AsPlainText
Export-PfxCertificate -Cert $cert -FilePath C:\https\aspnetapp.pfx -Password $password

# trust it on your host machine
$store = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store "TrustedPublisher","LocalMachine"
$store.Open("ReadWrite")
$store.Add($cert)
$store.Close()
```

Assuming you use Microsoft-supplied base images for your apps, to hint Kestrel to pick the new cert up you will probably have to [run docker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/docker-https?view=aspnetcore-3.1) like so:

```bsh
docker pull your_docker_image
docker run --rm -it -p 8000:80 -p 8001:443 -e ASPNETCORE_URLS="https://+;http://+" -e ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=8001 -e ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password="123123" -e ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=\https\aspnetapp.pfx -v %USERPROFILE%\.aspnet\https:C:\https\ your_docker_image

docker run <your image> --rm -it -p 8000:80 -p 8001:443 -e ASPNETCORE_URLS="https://+;http://+" -e ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=8001 -e ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password="123123" -e ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/https/aspnetapp.pfx
```

Note I'm exporting the cert to `C:\https` which then gets mounted onto the container.

You might have to play around with paths and domain names but hopefully that gives you a starting point.

[OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/) is another possible solution here that would be cross-platform as well

**UPD** Since Docker machines are often Linux, this answer might not be a complete solution. Check out my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62193586/12339804) on the same topic - that one leverages off OpenSSL to perform the task and goes into how to embed self-signed certs into Docker images on build.

Comment: I have tried your Powershell script, but it still works for localhost only. Chrome mentions that the certificate must be in Trusted Root Certification Authorities, otherwise it is not trusted. I have changed the trust to `$store = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreName]::Root,"LocalMachine"`, but I get the certificate within the Intermediate Certification Authorities. I have exported it and imported it into Trusted Root Certification Authorities and Chrome is still not happy.

Comment: Also directly imported the pfx into Trusted Root Certification Authorities certificates, but still not enough for Chrome.

Comment: Damn - I had to issue a `docker-compose build` to work properly. Thanks.