# ASP.NET Core Web API client does not trust self-signed certificate used by the Identity Server instance

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, ssl-certificate, identityserver4

This is a follow up of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61997345/how-to-allow-https-connections-from-both-localhost-and-container-towards-an-asp/62060315#62060315).

I have generated and trusted a self-signed certificate using the following script:

```
#create a SAN cert for both host.docker.internal and localhost
#$cert = New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName "host.docker.internal", "localhost" -CertStoreLocation "cert:\LocalMachine\Root" 
# does not work: New-SelfSignedCertificate : A new certificate can only be installed into MY store.
$cert = New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName "host.docker.internal", "localhost" -CertStoreLocation cert:\localmachine\my

#export it for docker container to pick up later
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "password_here" -Force -AsPlainText
Export-PfxCertificate -Cert $cert -FilePath "$env:USERPROFILE\.aspnet\https\aspnetapp.pfx" -Password $password

# trust it on your host machine
$store = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreName]::Root,"LocalMachine"
$store.Open("ReadWrite")
$store.Add($cert)
$store.Close()
```

When accessing `https://host.docker.internal:5500/.well-known/openid-configuration` and `https://localhost:5500/.well-known/openid-configuration` on the host machine, it works as expected (certificate is OK).

However, the Web API application running in the container is not happy with it:

```
web_api          | System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://host.docker.internal:5500/.well-known/openid-configuration'.
web_api          |  ---> System.IO.IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: 'https://host.docker.internal:5500/.well-known/openid-configuration'.
web_api          |  ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
web_api          |  ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
web_api          |    at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartSendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, ExceptionDispatchInfo exception)
```

The docker-compose file for the API is the following (relevant parts only):

```
  web.api:
    image: web_api_image
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: ProjectApi/Dockerfile
    environment: 
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=ContainerDev 
    container_name: web_api
    ports:
      - "5600:80"
    networks:
      - backend
      - data_layer
    depends_on:
      - identity.server
      - mssqlserver
      - web.cache

  identity.server:
    image: identity_server_image
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: MyProject.IdentityServer/Dockerfile
    environment: 
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=ContainerDev 
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=password_here
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/https/aspnetapp.pfx
    volumes:
      - ~/.aspnet/https:/https:ro
    container_name: identity_server
    ports:
      - "5500:443"
      - "5501:80"
    networks:
      - backend
      - data_layer
    depends_on:
      - mssqlserver
```

How can I make this work?

---

The call towards the identity server is done by setting up the security in API client to use it (no explicit HTTPS call):

```
/// <summary>
/// configures authentication and authorization
/// </summary>
/// <param name="services"></param>
/// <param name="configuration"></param>
public static void ConfigureSecurity(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    string baseUrl = configuration.GetSection("Idam").GetValue<string>("BaseUrl");
    Console.WriteLine($"Authentication server base URL = {baseUrl}");

    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    }).AddJwtBearer(o =>
    {
        o.MetadataAddress = $"{baseUrl}/.well-known/openid-configuration";
        o.Authority = "dev_identity_server";
        o.Audience = configuration.GetSection("Idam").GetValue<string>("Audience");
        o.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    });

    services.AddAuthorization();
}
```

---

#### Identity server configuration

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    string connectionStr = Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default");
    Console.WriteLine($"[Identity server] Connection string = {connectionStr}");

    services.AddDbContext<AppIdentityDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionStr));

    services.AddTransient<AppIdentityDbContextSeedData>();


    services.AddIdentity<AppUser, IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppIdentityDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    services.AddIdentityServer(act =>
        {
            act.IssuerUri = "dev_identity_server";
        })
        .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
        // this adds the operational data from DB (codes, tokens, consents)
        .AddOperationalStore(options =>
        {
            options.ConfigureDbContext = builder => builder.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default"));
            // this enables automatic token cleanup. this is optional.
            options.EnableTokenCleanup = true;
            options.TokenCleanupInterval = 30; // interval in seconds
        })
        //.AddInMemoryPersistedGrants()
        .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
        .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApiResources())
        .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients(Configuration))
        .AddAspNetIdentity<AppUser>();

    services.AddDataProtection()
        .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(@"\\UNC-PATH"));

    services.AddTransient<IProfileService, IdentityClaimsProfileService>();

    services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("AllowAll", p => p.AllowAnyOrigin()
       .AllowAnyMethod()
       .AllowAnyHeader()));

    services.AddMvc(options =>
    {
        options.EnableEndpointRouting = false;
    }).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Latest);
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public static void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, 
    ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, AppIdentityDbContextSeedData seeder)
{
    seeder.SeedTestUsers();
    IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseExceptionHandler(builder =>
    {
        builder.Run(async context =>
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
            context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

            var error = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
            if (error != null)
            {
                context.Response.AddApplicationError(error.Error.Message);
                await context.Response.WriteAsync(error.Error.Message).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
        });
    });

    // app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseCors("AllowAll");
    app.UseIdentityServer();

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

Comment: I’m guessing here, but maybe it’s because your SSL certificate is made for the domain “localhost”, and when docker containers call each other, they use the container name, not localhost.

Comment: @yesman - the certificate is generated for both "host.docker.internal" and "localhost" and Chrome validates this when accessing the URL for both cases. I am using `host.docker.internal` because it must be solved by both the API running in the container and the SPA working on my host machine.

Comment: you will need to have your docker containers trust the same certs now, I think. See if [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26028971/docker-container-ssl-certificates) points you in the right direction.

Comment: silly question but have you authorised docker access the folder containing the certificate? This caused me to lose couple hours unfortunately. Also could you share the service config code for your server where you declare consumption of SSL and such.

Comment: @Aeseir I am not sure about the answer for the first question: Docker for Windows is allowed to share files for both my drives. I have added the code that is using the identity server in my API.

Comment: @Alexei have you enabled UseHttpsRedirection()? Also to confirm you want to apply HTTPS to when accessing url not so much when services poll to verify the token? If not show me the code for Configure() in your startup

Comment: @Aeseir `UseHttpsRedirection` was not used inside the IdentityServer, but it does not seem to matter because I am directly accessing using `https`. I am also not using it for the API itself. Should I include the `Configure()` from the identity server or only the API one is relevant?

Comment: @Alexei thanks for extra info, i am going ask another silly question, are you passing the right password for the cert to docker? ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=password_here looks generic to me (unless it was on purpose)

Comment: @Aeseir Yes, I have replaced it with a generic password. `https://host.docker.internal:5500/.well-known/openid-configuration` works fine when accessing from the host (certificate is issued by `host.docker.internal` for `host.docker.internal`).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After a few attempts I gave up trying to get docker containers to trust a cert generated by `New-SelfSignedCertificate` (you may try and get it to work - concepts are exactly the same, it's just the certs are somehow different). I did however have success with [OpenSSL](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Binaries):

```bsh
$certPass = "password_here"
$certSubj = "host.docker.internal"
$certAltNames = "DNS:localhost,DNS:host.docker.internal,DNS:identity_server" # i believe you can also add individual IP addresses here like so: IP:127.0.0.1
$opensslPath="path\to\openssl\binaries" #assuming you can download OpenSSL, I believe no installation is necessary
$workDir="path\to\your\project" # i assume this will be your solution root
$dockerDir=Join-Path $workDir "ProjectApi" #you probably want to check if my assumptions about your folder structure are correct

#generate a self-signed cert with multiple domains
Start-Process -NoNewWindow -Wait -FilePath (Join-Path $opensslPath "openssl.exe") -ArgumentList "req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout ",
                                          (Join-Path $workDir aspnetapp.key),
                                          "-out", (Join-Path $dockerDir aspnetapp.crt),
                                          "-subj `"/CN=$certSubj`" -addext `"subjectAltName=$certAltNames`""

# this time round we convert PEM format into PKCS#12 (aka PFX) so .net core app picks it up
Start-Process -NoNewWindow -Wait -FilePath (Join-Path $opensslPath "openssl.exe") -ArgumentList "pkcs12 -export -in ", 
                                           (Join-Path $dockerDir aspnetapp.crt),
                                           "-inkey ", (Join-Path $workDir aspnetapp.key),
                                           "-out ", (Join-Path $workDir aspnetapp.pfx),
                                           "-passout pass:$certPass"

$password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $certPass -Force -AsPlainText
$cert = Get-PfxCertificate -FilePath (Join-Path $workDir "aspnetapp.pfx") -Password $password

# and still, trust it on your host machine
$store = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreName]::Root,"LocalMachine"
$store.Open("ReadWrite")
$store.Add($cert)
$store.Close()
```

I used plain Ubuntu image to be able to test this with `wget` but a quick check indicates that Microsoft images would support the same build steps:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

RUN  apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y wget \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

USER root 
###### you probably only care about the following three lines
ADD ./aspnetapp.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/asp_dev/
RUN chmod -R 644 /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/asp_dev/
RUN update-ca-certificates --fresh
######

ENTRYPOINT tail -f /dev/null
```

my `docker-compose` is pretty much identical to yours. I'll list it here for completeness:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  web_api:
    build: ./ProjectApi
    container_name: web_api
    ports:
      - "5600:80"
    depends_on:
      - identity_server

  identity_server:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/samples:aspnetapp    
    environment: 
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=password_here
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/https/aspnetapp.pfx
    volumes:
      - ~/.aspnet/https/:/https/:ro 
    container_name: identity_server
    ports:
      - "5500:443"
      - "5501:80"
```

With all of the above, I haven't tested running an actual .net core application as a client on a container - my test was a pretty simple `wget https://identity_server.docker.internal` command line.

So there's still a chance you might have issues. This would be due to the fact that some applications use their own trusted certs - see this [SE thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/90607) for more context.

Hopefully though, it's going to be a smooth ride from here.

Comment: I have made a few changes to make this work (`Start-Process -NoNewWindow -Wait`, otherwise the execution order was messed up; $Env:OPENSSL_CONF is not required). Those "three lines" were the missing magic in my rationale. Thank you for the full workflow.

Comment: I incorporated these changes into the answer so it's more relevant